# cvc4 error with LANG_AUTO and antlr

Tags: smt, cvc4

I've built cvc4 from source according to their manual [here](http://cvc4.cs.stanford.edu/wiki/Building_CVC4_from_source).
I ran `make check` which went perfect, then `sudo make install`.
Then, I've tried running a simple example that works with z3:

```
(declare-const i Int)
(declare-const j Int)

(assert (= i 5))
(assert (= (+ i j) 9))

(check-sat)
(get-value (i j))
```

But I get this error:

```
CVC4 Error:
internal error: unhandled language LANG_AUTO in AntlrInput::newInput
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I invoked it wrong from the command line. Here's what works:

```
cvc4 --quiet --produce-models --lang=smt2 ./example.txt
```

Which produces the following result:

```
sat
((i 5) (j 4))
```